# Calling startLeScan method multiple times doesn't scan BLE devices properly

Tags: android, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am trying to call startLeScan method multiple times in my Android application, it scan BLE devices for the first time, from second time onwards it's not able to scan devices. I have cyclic scan in my application and am stopping scan for every 10 sec and start again. Here are some logs which shows how my application behaves.

```
05-20 00:45:31.146  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.147  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.160  15841-15852/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
05-20 00:45:31.161  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.165  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.169  15841-15909/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=7
05-20 00:45:31.171  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.175  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.179  15841-15853/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=8
05-20 00:45:31.181  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.185  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.189  15841-18615/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=6
05-20 00:45:31.191  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.192  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.202  15841-15852/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=133 clientIf=0
05-20 00:45:31.203  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ stopLeScan()
05-20 00:45:31.207  15841-15841/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ startLeScan(): null
05-20 00:45:31.211  15841-15909/XXXXX D/BluetoothAdapter﹕ onClientRegistered() - status=0 clientIf=10
```

I have these function calls in my BluetoothLEScannerForMR2.java and when I call startScan method multiple times I got the above logs.

```
protected void startScan() {
    if (getBluetoothAdapter() != null) {
        if (getBluetoothAdapter().isEnabled()) {
            getBluetoothAdapter().startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanStopTime = new Date().getTime() + mScanPeriod;

            mScanning = true;

            handleIntervalScanning();
        }
    }
}

protected void stopScan() {
    if (getBluetoothAdapter() != null) {
        if (getBluetoothAdapter().isEnabled()) {
            getBluetoothAdapter().stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            mScanning = false;
        }
    }
}

private void handleIntervalScanning() {
    long msUntilNextStop = mScanStopTime - (new Date().getTime());

    if (msUntilNextStop > mScanPeriod)
        msUntilNextStop =  mScanPeriod;

    if (msUntilNextStop > 0) {
        mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                handleIntervalScanning();
            }
        }, msUntilNextStop);
    } else {
        if (getBluetoothAdapter() != null) {
            if (getBluetoothAdapter().isEnabled()) {
                if (mScanning) {
                    getBluetoothAdapter().stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                    startScan();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old post, but thought I'd comment in case others need help. In your code, you're getting an instance of the BlueToothAdapter and calling the startscan method...but your're not persisting that adapter instance.  Then in  your stopscan method, you create a new instance of a bluetooth adapter and call its stop scan.  I think you need to save the adapter to a memory variable when you "get" the adapter and then use the same instance of the adapter (via the memory variable) to stop the scan.